# How to mock a nested methods of a Scala Object using Mockito?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, scalatest

I am trying to create Unit tests for a Scala application. I am trying mock a method which is  inside a scala object with Mockito.
The method am trying to mock is calling a method of another object from different package.

**package1** -> method 1 (This is the method , which I am trying to mock its return output using MOckito )

**package2** -> method 2, method 3

```
 '''def method 1
{
//some code
 calling method 2()
 }
 
 def method 2
 {
 ///some code
 calling method 3
 }
```

I tried to mock the method 1 . But getting error 'NullPointerException' for method 2 and 3 .  I have read about RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS . But all my methods are define under Scala objects not under Class. Can we mock Scala Objects using REURNS_DEEP_STUBS?
Could anyone suggest some ideas?

Comment: `object`s are sort of singletons. You cannot mock them. (Actually you can with some libraries but if you have to mock it, chances are you have a design issue in the 1st place).

Comment: Mocking -> mocks are injectable to your logic through parameters/constructors -> you don't need to modify "globals" to test your code.